# Why apt can't upgrade some packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I have many `Ubuntu Desktop` 22.04 instances installed through either direct installation or VirtualBox. All of them installed in the same way. Sometimes and for few of them happens the following:

```bash
#1
sudo apt update
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
26 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

#2
sudo apt upgrade 
...

#3
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded. <-----

#4
sudo apt autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

#5
sudo apt clean
```

Observe in #3 the following part:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded
```

**Question**

- Why `apt` can't upgrade some packages?

If is re-executed *almost* the same process happens the following (Observe **#2** because is new and **#3** because has more details)

```bash
#1
sudo apt update
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

#2
apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libsmbclient/jammy-updates 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5]
libwbclient0/jammy-updates 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5]
samba-libs/jammy-updates 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5]

#3
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  imagemagick libopenexr25 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  imagemagick-6.q16 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsmbclient libwbclient0 samba-libs
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded. <---

#4
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

#5
sudo apt autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

#6
sudo apt clean
```

**Note** in others instances not always appears the following part

- `Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:`

Therefore it happens randomly and even in few instances of `Ubuntu Server`. If my memory does not fail me, I had this experience for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 too.

Comment: Have you read the `man` page for clues; there are cases (esp. on *alpha* or *beta*, but also when some sources are added) when `apt full-upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade` is needed to be run .. ie. from my release "*full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole*" where `apt upgrade` will leave those upgrades before so you can decide yourself when you using the `apt full-upgrade` command. Other reasons include ESP/Pro related packages (*need ESM/Pro to be enabled*) OR *phased* updates too.